# How do I inherit functions into an object and allow them to be used from given object?

Tags: perl

I'm having trouble putting this question to better words, but how might I accomplish something like this:

```
FileSpecClone.pm
package FileSpecClone;
use File::Spec::Unix;

sub new() {
bless {};
}

CloneScript.pl
use FileSpecClone;
$obj = FileSpecClone->new();
# A FileSpec::Unix subroutine
$obj->catpath('a','b','c');
```

Comment: You should get rid of the `()` in `sub new()`. Not only will `new` will be given an argument you should use, the prototype isn't checked for method calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify that `FileSpecClone` should inherit the methods of `File::Spec::Unix` by setting the package `@ISA` variable.

```
package FileSpecClone;
use File::Spec::Unix;
our @ISA = qw(File::Spec::Unix);
...
```

This is documented in [`perlobj`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlobj).

If you have the `parent` module (a core module since v5.10), that will handle the details of setting `@ISA` at compile time. (HT: daxim)

```
use parent 'File::Spec::Unix';
```

Comment: [Best practice](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/blead/pod/perlootut.pod): `use parent 'File::Spec::Unix';` instead of fiddling with @ISA.